# Imputing with MissForest, should I keep categorical variables with no missing data in inputs

Tags: python, categorical-data, data-imputation

I have a dataset with missing values that I'm trying to impute thanks to MissForest algorithm using python missingpy library.

To my understanding, I should keep in the inputs even columns with no missing values as they carry information for the random forest models training.

However, for categorical variable with no missing value, I obtain the warning message below (but still work)

```
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in long_scalars
  (Ximp[:, self.cat_vars_] != Ximp_old[:, self.cat_vars_])) / n_catmissing
```

Am I right to keep categorical variables with no missing data in my inputs even though it returns a warning ?